# Arabic text summarization using bert (araBert)

Tags: arabic, bert-language-model, summarization

Among models that summarize the Arabic texts, I chose AraBert.

After installing the necessary tools and libraries,
I want to know how do I use this model for summarization if some of you have already used it?
What are the steps or the instructions that I must follow I am still a beginner in this field?

Could you please guide me?

https://huggingface.co/ahmeddbahaa/AraBART-finetuned-ar

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AraBert for summarization due to summarization is NLU (Natural Language Understanding) and it's advanced, so you need large corpus like how they trained Bert for English language.
You can use AraBert for NER ,sentiment analysis and question answering.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I appreciate your help but I changed my mind about using this model and the Arabic language due to the lack of resources.